# uploading image in php

Tags: php, html, image, upload

I'm trying to get an upload system going, which also logs the name of the file you uploaded and some other data to a mysql database. The logging of the name is working, but i cant seem to actually upload the image. It's nowhere to be found =(

HTML:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<td>Photo/Video of the mistake</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
<input type="file" name="photo"> 
</td>
```

PHP

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","erlend","123","epicsoft");
$host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 
$username="erlend"; // Mysql username 
$password="123"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="epicsoft"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="bugs"; // Table name 


$path="images/bugs"."/". basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select database");

$spill = $_POST['spill']; 
$tidspunkt = $_POST['tidspunkt'];
$rapportør = $_POST['rapportør'];
$beskrivelse = $_POST['beskrivelse'];
$media=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (spill, tidspunkt, rapportør, media, beskrivelse)
  VALUES ('$spill', '$tidspunkt', '$rapportør', '$media', '$beskrivelse')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: That's because you don't actually even attempt to upload the image. You also mixed mysql and mysqli functions which won't help your situation.

Comment: Why are you calling *both* `mysqli_connect` and `mysql_connect`?  What's the point of that?

Comment: Please see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Also this code is *very* unsafe.  Use prepared statements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Sorry, but i cant really see the difference between my code and the one linked from php.net? Looking at the first example, it seems like its exactly the same. Also, the mess in the use of mysql and mysqli should not prohibit me from uploading files should it? Considering i can access the database fine even with these mistakes, i cant see that this could be that cause, i could easily be mistaken ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` ( `spill`, `tidspunk`, `rapportør`, `media`, `beskrivelse`)  VALUES ('$spill', '$tidspunkt', '$rapportør', '$media', '$beskrivelse');";
```